# Importing "parent-sharing" modules from different eggs

Tags: python, package, egg

When there is `a.x` in `x.egg`, and `a.y` in `y.egg`, is it possible to import all `a`, `a.x`, and `a.y` from these eggs?

From my experience, I am expecting a negative answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `import foo as bar` syntax to assign different names:

```
from x import a as ax
from y import a as ay
```

Comment: Sadly, what I want to do is `from a import x, y`, not `from {x,y} import a`.
And though I did not mention in the previous post,
I want to release `x.egg (a.x)` and `y.egg (a.y)` independently.
Where `a` becomes something like my id.
And I am afraid that, it is impossible.

If it is truly impossible, I know that I can release them as `ax` and `ay`.